# Modifying elements of an iframe with local source with Chrome extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm working away at a `Chrome` extension right now, but I'm running into permission/security issues. I have a local `HTML` template file which I am inserting into a floating `iframe` on certain web pages. I have certain information retrieved from `AJAX` / cookies which I want to insert into the template. When I do this, I am met with an error:

Some relevant code:

```
$(this).after('<div id=\"flowframe\"><iframe src=\"'+chrome.extension.getURL('hoverwindow.html')+'\"></iframe></div>');
$('iframe').contents().find('#description').html(data.description);
```

The second line throws the error:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement' 
Blocked a frame with origin "http://ugradcalendar.uwaterloo.ca" from accessing a frame with origin "chrome-extension://kdjcjbijngfephllebpnahpodnbcnhlo".  
The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "chrome-extension". Protocols must match.
```

I think I have my manifest set up properly, but am not entirely sure:

```
...
"web_accessible_resources": ["loading.gif", "hoverwindow.html"],
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["http://ugradcalendar.uwaterloo.ca/*"],
  "css": ["extension-styling.css"],
  "js": ["jquery-1.11.3.js","js.cookie.js","script.js"],
  "all_frames": true
}
],
"permissions": [
  "activeTab",
  "cookies",
  "http://uwflow.com/",
  "https://uwflow.com/",
  "http://ugradcalendar.uwaterloo.ca/",
  "https://ugradcalendar.uwaterloo.ca/"
]
```

Comment: The chrome extension only allows you to access each frame, it doesn't allow each frame to access each other, these limitations still fall under the typical browser requirements.  Try looking into postmessage for a solution for communicating across frames.

Answer (score 1):

So, a couple days later and I found a solution that works for me. I didn't end up having any success with `iframe` for this.

Since my template was a local file, I learned I could simply `$.load()` the template into an absolute-position `div` and save myself the headache of `postMessage` errors and other `iframe` quirks.

For reference, in case anybody runs into a similar problem with trying to use local `html` in an `iframe`, the way I did this:

```
$('body').after('<div id=\"flowframe\"></div>'); 
$('#flowframe').load(chrome.extension.getURL("hoverwindow.html"));
```

Then I am able to directly modify elements of `hoverwindow.html` on the same domain without issues.